# Duplex service not working on IIS (without anonymous access)

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I am trying to run my application in a deployed-like way. So in Internet Information Services from Administrative Tools I created a virtual folder. Also in "Properties window->Directory Security tab->Authentication window" I unchecked "Anonymous access" and checked "Integrated Windows authentication" (application requirement).

The problem is that I have a WCF duplex service that requires anonymous access. But if I set that in IIS settings (see above) I can't log.

Is there any way of making this work? Maybe create an exception for allowing a specific service anonymous access?

**EDIT:**
I have found the following possible solution:

```
  <pollingDuplexHttpBinding>
    <binding name="mypollingDuplexHttpBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <!-- When deploying to IIS, clientCredentialType should match the IIS authentication method -->
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </pollingDuplexHttpBinding>
```

Funny thing: works the first build but not from the second. Then works only if I create a new virtual folder.

**EDIT:** I am testing my application in IIS 5 on a XP machine.